# IE7 IE8 Misinterpreting EMs in layout?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The website is [www.holmecourt.com](http://www.holmecourt.com), and it renders exactly as I intend it to in Safari and IE9, this screenshot is viewed directly in Safari, which looks exactly the same in Adobe Browserlab for IE9: http://holmecourt.com/images/scrn1.png

However, the problem is that Browserlab shows IE8 as following, with IE7 pretty similar: http://holmecourt.com/images/scrn2.png

Ie7/8 previously displayed well when I was using pixels everywhere, but since changing everything to ems, IE7/8 seem not to like it.

I have searched for IE bugs with em, but could not find any, I was wondering if there are known bugs in how IE7/8 renders ems in layout?

Otherwise is there anything that a more experienced developer might notice in just comparing the screenshots, I thought it might be relevant that as well as the layout breaking, the text is not sized correctly, so perhaps its a problem with font-size being inherited?

Comment: This might help you? http://css-class.com/test/bugs/ie/ie7-font-size-bug-with-ems.htm

Comment: That is interesting, thanks very much, looks to me as though IE7 is just behaving in a non-standard way and that I can't help that

Comment: No worries.. There is something you can do to help it anyway using ie specific css files. I've created an answer to help explain.

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve] and thus can't be answered. On top of that, you appear to have solved it in a way that is not reproducible by others (you removed conditional comments from some shim you were using), making this also closeable as no-repro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so in case anyone has a similar problem, I've realised what was happening!

I accidentally removed the HTML5 Shiv when I removed some conditional comments. This completely changed how IE 8 and below rendered HTML5 elements.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Answer (score -1):

You can implement specific style sheets to load conditionally for ie. In the head section of html:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This would load an ie specific .css file only when using ie8 or lower. You can then put your overrides in the ie.css file to let it display correctly in those versions.

Comment: I've used that before, but this seems a "nicer" method for targeting specific versions of IE to me, what do you think? http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: That is an interesting method. It depends how much extra css you'll need to make for it display correctly in ie. If it's a lot, then you'd be loading those ie only css rules for all browsers unnecessarily. Using the .css file method would only be an extra http request for ie browsers. So it depends on what browser you think your users will use the most as well.